# helm-project-switch-project in other window

Tags: window, helm, projectile

Often i have a need to open a file from the other projectile-based project in another window. I'm using `helm` with projectile, so there's a function `helm-projectile-switch-project` (which i guess by default is bound to `C-c p p`). I'd like to join it with std `C-x 4` command, i.e to have a function which opens a file from a different project in another window, similar to `C-c p 4 f`. I couldn't find anything like this in the helm codebase and current implementation for `projectile-find-file-other-window` didn't shed the light how i can do this myself.

Comment: You don't need another command to open files in other window. Just use the usual command, move cursor to a file and press "C-c o" to open in other wimdow.

Comment: @TuDo Thanks a lot. I'm ready to mark it as an answer, though a quick question, is there any utility function like `other-window` which display any output in a different window, like `(other-window (function-which-returns-something))`?

Comment: as far as I know, there's none. You don't store your returned output in a window, but a buffer. Then select a window and switch buffer to it. You can create other window and switch to your buffer like this: `(with-selected-window (select-window (split-window-horizontally))  (switch-to-buffer your-buffer) (message "Hello or do something else"))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need another command to open files in other window. Just use the usual command, move cursor to a file and press <kbd>C-c o</kbd> to open in other wimdow.

Comment: This is great!  But, where is `C-c o` documented?  How could I have found this in Emacs's docs (and where can I find other such keys)?